# How to generate an 'angular.json' file

Tags: angular-cli

My current application was in Angular 4 without Angular CLI. So I never had a *[angular.json](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config)* file or Angular-cli.json file. Now we want to generate that Angular CLI or *angular.json* file. Because this file is not available it is not taking any of the `ng` commands like `ng serve` or `ng g c testing`.

How can I generate the file without using the `ng new` command, because `ng new` will create a new project which I don't want. I want to support my existing project.

Few notes on my project:

1. We are launching multiple applications from one folder
2. We are launching each application from the ASPX page without using *index.html*.

Please see the screenshot attached of the error and the folder structure of my project

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPHx9.png)

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyXHC.png)

Comment: you need to generate it manually

Comment: @Akash Surana: From angular >= 6 '.angular-cli.json' file is replaced by 'angular.json' file. as your project is based on angular 4 that you have said so you need to create '.angular-cli.json' file not 'angular.json' file.

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 2):

Create a new file with name '.angular-cli.json' and add this file in your main directory.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "my-app"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Angular >= 6 '.angular-cli.json' file is replaced by the 'angular.json' file. As your project is based on Angular 4 that you have said so you need to create '.angular-cli.json' file not 'angular.json' file.

As you have ready made project of Angular 4 and you want to generate file command (as you mentioned above) like:

```
ng g c sample
```

So I assume you have installed the latest Angular CLI in globally.

You can make a trick. Just create a new project in another location and copy that '.angular-cli.json' file in your desired project folder. After that, just change the project name and other things which is relevant to your need. Create a '.angular-cli.json' file in own hand is a little bit tedious and time-consuming also as you know. And if you already have CLI installed then I think no need to create it manually which may cause you compiling error also. That's all my friend. You can also use this '.angular-cli.json' below if you want:

```javascript
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "angular-app"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```