# Angular Application Build Issue

Tags: angular, angular-cli

We have a project on angular (angular CLI version 7.0.6) When we are trying to build this project through cmd "ng serve" it is showing error "The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found"

We have checked and found that angular.json file is missing in our project. Is there a way we can resolve this issue or we can draw a stretch project including old files?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55038367/how-to-generate-angular-json-file/55038490) and see if that helps you.

Source control is certainly something you should look into to avoid situations like loss of a file.   Git with GitHub is a great one for private or public repositories if you need one.